# PACT - Contract deployment in Chainweaver, issue resolving for Fungible-v2.Account-Details

Tags: pact, pact-lang

getting acquainted with chainweaver and pact for deploying. I cannot get to deployment, i have an error when forking anedak or coin.pact to deploy. I load fungible-v2 into my repl as it is required, and go to deploy with my admin-keyset as defined. The error in ENV shows that it "cannot resolve "fungible-v2.account-details"
[image: sc1]
[image: sc2]
Am i meant to fill in account details?

I have defined my namespace free, write and read keysets to my admin-keyset with an  active account on chain 1 with tKDA

see above,

(namespace "free")

(define-keyset "admin-keyset")

(read-keyset "admin-keyset")

defined

deploy - changed anedak to test - and expected to see the coin deploy with the option to configure and poke around with a live contract on testnet
[image: sc3]

[image]

EDIT: silly mistake, I did not realize we needed to have always unqiue keypair names. This is my error though, my account is not able to pay the gas

[sc4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhRQ3.png)

Comment: I have removed the Haskell tag because there's no obvious connection to Haskell here. The code you've included in your image looks like some flavor of Lisp.

Comment: Please do not use images to present text. Instead, copy and paste text, and use Markdown for formatting, hyperlinking, etc.

Comment: thanks, sorry my first post. and ofc some of this was answered as i posted for help..
Ill likely post a better formatted question and remove this one, thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is a signing error for the admin keyset.
The fungible-v2 in REPL is unrelated - the blockchain knows that this exists.

Make sure you've

- Selected the right account when deploying
- Selected a key in unrestricted signing keys with a keyset from the admin-keyset
- DO NOT use a keyset from the admin keyset when signing gas capability - leave that empty

If you're concerned that it might be to do with fungible v2, you might want to first check if you have issues deploying a normal hello world smart contract like in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kitty.kad.token/writing-a-basic-smart-contract-on-kadena-hello-world-5a7440b46b35)